# Can I restrict packages have some set of functions in Golang?

Tags: go, interface, structure

I have packages, that are similar in functionality, as they are web request handlers.

I have functions like this for Home page in each package:

```
package home_page_handler


func GetUrl() string {
    return "/"
}

func GetPageName() string {
    return "HomePage"
}
```

To structure the code better, I wonder if I can add a restriction, may be via interfaces to make each package of some "class" contain these functions?

That way if I add one more handler, it will throw an error while compiling if a function is missing or has a wrong signature.

Comment: If a function is missing and you try to call it, the compiler will raise the issue.
If a function is missing and nobody calls it, why bother?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could "register" each package with a call

```
package server

type PageHandler {
    url, name func() string
}

var Handlers = []PageHandler

func RegisterHandler(url func()string, name func()string) {
    Handlers = append(Handlers, PageHandler{url, name})
}

...

package home_page

...

func init() {
    server.RegisterHandler(GetUrl, GetPageName)
}
```

The package won't compile unless `GetUrl` and `GetPageName` are provided and the function signature is correct.